# kproto function of clustMixType r package

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am trying to run a kprototype clustering algorithm on my data using the kproto function of the clustMixType package in R but it's not working
I have 1000 rows and 5 variables: only one is categorical, the others have been scaled (still not working when not scaled)

It keeps saying:

> Estimated lambda: Inf 
>   Equal prototyps merged. Cluster number reduced to: 3 
>   Error in table(clusters) : all arguments must have the same length
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In kproto.default(inputdata_test, 4) :
>   All categorical variables have zero variance.

Or my categorical variable has at least 3 attributes, the numeric variables all have at least 2 distinct values and there is no NaN values in the dataframe.

There is a small extract of my data below

[image: data]

Comment: with the latest version (0.1-17) it should work

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use scale function() in kproto. but use it when you use k-means.
Second, Change the character of categorical feature as number. For example, Other=1, Tablet=2, Mobile Phone=3 ...

And, When i see your error message..

> all arguments must have the same length In addition

this means your data rows of variable is different. so check your data set.

And,

> All categorical variables have zero variance.

this means categorical variable has problem in variance.
check as this code.

```
lambdaest(df of kproto)
```

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

kproto also throws `Error in table(clusters) : all arguments must have the same length` if there are NAs in the data.

I fixed this using `na.omit` on my data frame.